# Is Carol Danvers called Captain Marvel in universe

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

So I'll start by saying Brie Larson's Carol Danvers is Captain Marvel and we should all call her that.

My question is though is the title diegetic? Can we expect anyone in the movies to call her that?

I don't think anyone was called by their rank in the movie and I can't tell from the uniforms but both Carol Danvers/Vers and Dr. Wendy Lawson/Mar-vell could've been a Captain in the Air Force/Starforce.

Did I miss something about Carol taking on her mentors name or something or is Captain Marvel just what we, the viewers, call the character in the real world? It didn't seem like she needed or wanted a secret identity, she could just go by Carol.

Comment: Is Captain Marvel unusual in this? I feel like some of the characters didn't get their name mentioned in their first movie.

Comment: @Obie2.0 who else though? At least in the MCU. Maybe Hulk?

Comment: @Paul D. Waite Looks like it happened to Black Widow and Hawkeye. Scarlet Witch I think still hasn't been called by that name. They weren't titular characters in their own movie though.

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94358/are-agent-barton-and-agent-romanoff-ever-called-hawkeye-and-black-widow-in-t

Comment: @DonaldAnderson: yeah I think Wanda Maximoff is just Wanda Maximoff in the MCU, likewise her brother (RIP Pietro). There's not been any reference to them having made-up names. Good shout about Black Widow and Hawkeye. I can't quite remember the latter gets referred to by name at all in Thor, although I presume someone at least calls him Agent Barton.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Hulk was called such in *The Incredible Hulk*, by one of the onlookers of the Culver University battle interviewed by the news.

Comment: Don't forget about Thor obviously, and the classic "I am Iron Man" at the end of the first movie :) Event Spiderman is called that way in his first appearance in *Captain America: Civil War*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not diegetic, it's just not said out loud. It is an origin movie after all. As for the components, it is shown that she was Captain Carol Denvers in the movie. Her mentor was named Mar-vell (or Marvel, still not sure on that), and she aims to continue her mission. She proudly wears her jacket at the end of the movie. From those bits, we can safely assume that she's taking this identity as her own. It will probably be dropped in Endgame when she has to introduce herself to the Avengers.

Comment: Spider-man uses Captain Marvel to refer to her in Far from Home

Answer (score 8):

In *Spider-Man: Far from Home*, Spider-Man mentions Captain Marvel. Making him the first MCU character to refer to Carol as "Captain Marvel."

When Nick Fury tells Spider-Man that he needs Spider-Man, Peter asks about other Avengers, including Captain Marvel.

The *Far from Home* trailer shows this.