# Did anyone call Carol Danvers Captain Marvel?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, captain-marvel

I don't remember that anyone referred to her as Captain Marvel in her solo movie. Did anyone in Avengers call her Captain Marvel? If so, why? Did she introduce herself as Captain Marvel?

If not, is that mean, we don't have Captain Marvel, Captain Danvers instead?

Comment: Closely related (since you're asking about a different movie). [Is Carol Danvers called Captain Marvel in universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/97794/27264)

Comment: We don't know but since what we _do_ know is that she's called that way on the next Spider-Man movie (cf trailer), I think this might need to be put on hold until July.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### As of close of *Endgame*, no-one (even herself) has referred to her as "Captain Marvel".

In *Captain Marvel*, she is referred to as "Vers", "Carol" and "Carol Danvers".

In *Endgame* she's barely referenced and then only as "Carol".

The trailer for "Spider-Man: Far From Home" does have Peter Parker calling her "Captain Marvel" but it's not yet known whether this is her "official in-universe" name or just Peter getting confused and making one up.

It's unlikely that we'll get a proper answer to this "proper name" issue 
--until Phase 4 and/or *Captain Marvel 2"*